# React inline Styling not applying

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Hey guys I am just trying to render a set of paragraphs that contain news articles. I am using the inline styling method creating an object and assigning its value to the `<h2>` tag using the style attribute.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect } from 'react';


const App = () => {

    //inLineStyles
    const useStyle = {
    backgroundColor: "#282c34",
    color: "white",
    padding: "40px",
    fontFamily: "Arial",
    textAlign: "center",
    };


    //State
    const [news, setNews] = useState([]);
    const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("")
    const [url, setUrl] = useState("http://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=Hacker")
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    //APIcall
    const fetchNews = () => {
        setLoading(true);
        fetch(url)
            .then(responce => responce.json())
            .then(data => (setNews(data.hits), setLoading(false)))
            .catch(error => console.log(error))

    }
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchNews();
    }, [url])

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setSearchQuery(e.target.value)

    }
    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setUrl(`http://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=${searchQuery}`)
    }

    const handleLoading = () => {

        if (loading) {
            return <h2> Loading...</h2>
        }
        else {
            return 
        }
    }


return (
    <div>
        <h1 style={useStyle}>News </h1>
         { handleLoading() }
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input type='text' value={searchQuery} onChange={handleChange}/>
                <button>Search</button>
            </form>
        {news.map((n, i) => (
            <p key={i}> {n.title} </p>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Can you please let me know why the style is  not applied?
Thanks!

Comment: this is working correctly. check your tag to see if e.g. an `!important` is set in a css.

Comment: You can get solution from here https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_css.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was stuck on this for half of the day. I finally was able to do figure it out. All I had to do was to refresh the page in the browser(I was saving and compiling the code in the code editor and for some reason it wasn't updating the web page). If someone might know why this happened please comment it on here.

Thanks for all the replies!